# Algorithm for the distance among nearest vectors

Tags: algorithm, vector, nearest-neighbor, np-hard

Given n vectors of dimension m. For every vector, each dimension can be replaced by the other dimension value of this vector, and each value can only be used only one time to replace the other dimension. After the changing of all these n vectors, we calculate the Manhattan distance between each vector and its nearest vector. For all the replacing plans, we select the one which can get the minimum sum of the distance between all these n vectors and these nearest vectors.
Is it NP-hard?

Comment: It's unclear what "For every vector, each dimension can be replaced by the other dimension value of this vector" means.  Can you add an example?

Comment: Suppose that we have a vector (A1, A2, .., An). And we can use any of these n values to represent the new vector after changing. For example, we can use A2 to replace the first dimension value, and use A3 and A1 to replace the second and third dimension values separately. We thus get the new vector (A2,A3,A1, ..., An).

Comment: Sounds like an assignment that you're asking the community to answer for you. Also, there's no programming question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the optimal configuration will *always* be to rearrange each row so that its entries are in ascending order.  So the optimal runtime should be O(m n log m), the amount of time it takes to sort n lists of length m.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one important constraint, which is the total times of replacing should be less than a given threshold C. That is, we cannot rearrange each row.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: Algorithms questions are off-topic?  I don't see anything about that in the rules.